# Swift - Core data gets overwritten

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to save the properties from the messages that I'm sending, to my core data. But every time I'm saving new messages, they don't append the existing ones, they just overwrite the whole entity. I hope you understand what I mean.

My code looks like this, were my receivers are being retrieved from another VC:

```
    var receivers: [String] = []

        @IBAction func doneTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

            for receiver in receivers{

                var textMessage = PFObject(className:"textMessage")
                textMessage["Receiver"] = receiver
                textMessage["Message"] = messageOutl.text
                textMessage.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {

                    (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                    if (success != nil) {

                        self.errorOccurred = true

                        NSLog("Object created with id: \(textMessage.objectId)")

                    } else {
                        NSLog("%@", error)
                    }
                }
            }
            let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
            let contxt: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
            let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("MainTable", inManagedObjectContext: contxt)

            var newMessage = SecondModel(entity: en!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contxt)

            for rec in receivers{
                newMessage.receiver = rec
                newMessage.date = NSDate()
                newMessage.messageType = typeOfMessage
                contxt.save(nil)
            }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this or why this happens would be appreciated.

EDIT: I changed my "en" and "newMessage" to this:

```
let en: AnyObject! = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MainTable", inManagedObjectContext: contxt)

var newMessage = SecondModel(entity: en! as NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contxt)
```

but now I get an "(lldb)" error in the second line.

EDIT 2: I solved the issue by getting rid of the second for-loop and instead putting the "save-to-core-data" code in the first for-loop. I still don't know why the first code shouldn't work though.

Answer (score 4):

To insert into CoreData, you need to use

```
let en = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName( "MainTable", inManagedObjectContext: contxt) as YourType // If you have a custom type
```

when you create the entity.

Then you typically save with something like this:

```
var error: NSError?
if !contxt.save(&error) {
    println("Error: \(error)")
    abort() 
}
```

It looks like you're doing:

```
let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("MainTable", inManagedObjectContext: contxt)
```

to create the entity, but the `entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` class method, according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEntityDescription/entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:), "Returns the entity with the specified name from the managed object model associated with the specified managed object context’s persistent store coordinator."

You don't want to **get** the object you've persisted; you want to **create** an object and persist it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: To clarify, `entityForName` just returns the NSEntityDescription, which is sort of like the schema of a Core Data object. It describes things like what sorts of attributes an object of the type that entity describes can have, but is not a managed object itself.